GitHub Actions Custom Runner Permission
I have installed a self-hosted GitHub Action runner as a windows service. The problem is that the  runner is not allowed to execute commands which are in my *.vcxproj file. On such commads create a file. How do I fix this

There is a discussion about this topic on GH that I have used in similar scenarios as a solution - https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/408
TLDR; you should be able to use powershell "(Get-Service actions.runner.*).name" to find the name of the GitHub Actions service, and then sc config "NAME_OF_YOUR_SERVICE" obj= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" type= own in this case to update it to run as the system, but you can change this to the user you need.
Another approach is to go to Services in Windows, find the GH Action service, and change the log on account under properties to a user that has the rights you need or adjust the system account as needed (ex: allowing it to interact with the desktop).
